# How to resize a image in Objective - C to a smaller version of it?

Tags: iphone

I have three images(.png format). I combine three images and create a speech bubble using drawInRect() for images and  I specify the rectangle in which each single image is drawn.

I have created resizable images for each of the images using resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake.

My original images are quite big. and hence, when I add text which consists of only few characters, the speech bubble that is drawn looks bigger for the text.

Can anyone tell me how to shrink the images such a way that it surrounds the text appropriately.

My speech bubble has a top image and its original height is 17pixels and hence if I use drawInRect() with a rectangle below that height, part of the image gets clipped, so is the case with the bottom image.

Any help is appreciated. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

We need to resize the image to our need, sample code snippet:

```
    CGSize imageSize = CGSizeMake(320,480); // give any desired size you want

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(itemSize);//Creates a bitmap-based graphics context

    CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, imageSize.width, imageSize.height);//modify

    [myimage drawInRect:imageRect];


    myimage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();  //returns new image

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
 - (UIImage*)imageByScalingAndCroppingForSize:(CGSize)targetSize
{
UIImage *sourceImage = self;
UIImage *newImage = nil;        
CGSize imageSize = sourceImage.size;
CGFloat width = imageSize.width;
CGFloat height = imageSize.height;
CGFloat targetWidth = targetSize.width;
CGFloat targetHeight = targetSize.height;
CGFloat scaleFactor = 0.0;
CGFloat scaledWidth = targetWidth;
CGFloat scaledHeight = targetHeight;
CGPoint thumbnailPoint = CGPointMake(0.0,0.0);

if (CGSizeEqualToSize(imageSize, targetSize) == NO) 
{
    CGFloat widthFactor = targetWidth / width;
    CGFloat heightFactor = targetHeight / height;

    if (widthFactor > heightFactor) 
        scaleFactor = widthFactor; // scale to fit height
    else
        scaleFactor = heightFactor; // scale to fit width.

    scaledWidth  = width * scaleFactor;
    scaledHeight = height * scaleFactor;

    // center the image
    if (widthFactor > heightFactor)
    {
        thumbnailPoint.y = (targetHeight - scaledHeight) * 0.5; 
    }
    else 
        if (widthFactor < heightFactor)
        {
            thumbnailPoint.x = (targetWidth - scaledWidth) * 0.5;
        }
}       

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(targetSize); // this will crop

CGRect thumbnailRect = CGRectZero;
thumbnailRect.origin = thumbnailPoint;
thumbnailRect.size.width  = scaledWidth;
thumbnailRect.size.height = scaledHeight;

[sourceImage drawInRect:thumbnailRect];

newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
if(newImage == nil) 
NSLog(@"could not scale image");

//pop the context to get back to the default
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return newImage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try with this method:

```
-(UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage *)imageToCompress scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize {

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.0);
    [imageToCompress drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this method for resizing image

```
-(UIImage *)resizeImage:(UIImage *)image width:(int)wdth height:(int)hght{
    int w = image.size.width;
    int h = image.size.height;
    CGImageRef imageRef = [image CGImage];
    int width, height;
    int destWidth = wdth;
    int destHeight = hght;
    if(w > h){
        width = destWidth;
        height = h*destWidth/w;
    }
    else {
        height = destHeight;
        width = w*destHeight/h;
    }
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef bitmap;
    bitmap = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, width, height, 8, 4 * width, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);

    if (image.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationLeft) {

        CGContextRotateCTM (bitmap, M_PI/2);
        CGContextTranslateCTM (bitmap, 0, -height);

    } else if (image.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationRight) {

        CGContextRotateCTM (bitmap, -M_PI/2);
        CGContextTranslateCTM (bitmap, -width, 0);

    }
    else if (image.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationUp) {

    } else if (image.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationDown) {

        CGContextTranslateCTM (bitmap, width,height);
        CGContextRotateCTM (bitmap, -M_PI);
    }

    CGContextDrawImage(bitmap, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), imageRef);
    CGImageRef ref = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmap);
    UIImage *result = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:ref];
    CGContextRelease(bitmap);
    CGImageRelease(ref);

    return result;

}
```